# Script for 3D viewport in rendered mode seems to have timing problem

Tags: python, rendering, scripting

When running this script, the 3D viewport in rendered shading doesn't update properly, compared to script-saved screenshots, or manually generating the screen (typing lines of python in the python window).  I've abstracted down as far as I can. There are mismatches of face color patterns, of rotation (bottom, 4th "frame" of 9) and incomplete rendering (top).

I've had some problems framing this question correctly. If it can be improved please let me know.

TOP:   manual OS screenshot, cropped to match

MIDDLE: manual rendering with typed lines of python, followed by Blender screenshot of viewport. This is what I expect to see in all three windows.

BOTTOM: screen-shots saved by the script.

My main question - what can I do to my script, to make the 3D viewport render completely (top image). Secondary question, are there other timing problems that can cause the glitches (like incorrect rotation and different pattern in bottom image).

[image]

To run script, add a light, add two nodes materials to the monkey, select monkey as active, set 3D viewport to "rendered"

```
import bpy
import bmesh
import time
import math
context = bpy.context
for area in context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == "VIEW_3D":
        ctx = { "window": context.window, "area": area, "region":None}
        break
US = lambda: bpy.ops.wm.redraw_timer(type='DRAW_WIN_SWAP', iterations=1)
ao = bpy.context.active_object
path = "/Users/tmp/"
for i in range(9):
    ao.rotation_euler = ((0.0, 0.0, math.pi*i/4.0))
    US()
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    ao.select = True
    bpy.context.scene.objects.active = ao
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
    bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(ao.data)
    for k, f in enumerate(bm.faces): 
        if k%(i+2):
            f.material_index = 1
        else:
            f.material_index = 0
    ao.data.update()
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
    time.sleep(2.0)
    file = "ao2_" + str(1000+i) + ".png"
    bpy.ops.screen.screenshot(ctx, filepath=path+file, full=False)
```

Comment: I didn't have much time to see into this, but can you test and this? https://gist.github.com/zeffii/afd28ce54d8fef9ded1d it should be functionally equivalent, and a further reduction in code

Comment: OK I'll take a look.

Comment: I like your script, I can see it's a more direct way. It definitely performs differently, and better, which is a good sign. Still some glitches, but fewer now. I'll continue to try variations as you suggest and update here. Thanks @zeffii !